# My app shows as enhanced by developer for wear OS on google play.But I've developed it for Phones.What went wrong?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have published an app on google play store. But in app's More Info section it shows as 'enhanced by the developer for wear OS'. I've designed it for Phones. How to change it to Phones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem resolved by removing the code that I wrote in the Manifest file for making the app indexable/searchable.
Hope this will help.